# Интерпритация SQL скрипта Sybase ->Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

Подскажите пож, как реализовать подобный скрипт в синтаксисе Oracle

```
declare @var varchar(255)
set @var = ''

update table set @var = @var+','+ field , state = 1
select @var
```

Данный скрипты бежит по табе, апдейтить по одной записи статус, добавит через запятую в переменную поле field из каждой строки table

как такое наваять на Oracle?

Comment: есть одна маленькая проблемка, последняя строчка не переводима на оракл по той причине, что блок pl/sql кода не может просто взять и вернуть выборку из таблицы. переменная, объявленная внутри pl/sql либо может быть возвращена из функции как значение, либо использована в другом pl/sql коде, но в клиента она тогда вообще не попадет. Так что лучше опишите какова цель всего этого и как это используется из клиента

Comment: А так в принципе надо сделать отдельно update и после него select который построит строку

Comment: Цель - выбрать пачку записей из таблицы, получить по ним первичные ключи и заапдейтить какое-либо поле - так я наложу лочки на эти записи и закрою для редактирования другими процессами, вернув в свое приложение стрингу со списком ключей, выберу их селектом, проанализирую, заапдейчу эти записи нужным мне статусом и закрою транзакцию - отпущу лочки. Скрипт буду дергать из джава-приложения

Comment: Это какой то слишком сложный путь. Вам достаточно выбрать ключи интересующих записей обычным select с добавлением фразы `for update` и они будут залочены для последующего обновления до окончания транзакции. Кроме этого обращаю ваше внимание, что в пределах транзакции oracle обеспечивает непротиворечивость чтения. сколько бы раз вы не выполняли select из таблицы в пределах транзакции вы ее будете видеть такой какой она была на момент первого обращения к ней с учетом ваших апдейтов.

Comment: О, огонь, LOCK IN SHARE MODE или FOR UPDATE то что мне нужно,спасибо!